# Using single Redux reducer to get and store multiple results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am wanting to use Redux to perform multiple dispatches to the same endpoint to fetch different responses, however I am unsure of how I can best store them within the Redux store...

**myAction.js**

```
export const GET_DATA = 'GET_DATA';
export const GET_DATA_SUCCESS = 'GET_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const GET_DATA_ERROR = 'GET_DATA_ERROR';

export const getData = (path) => ({
    type: GET_DATA,
    agent: agent.getData.get,
    agentData: path
});
```

**myReducer.js**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    ...

    switch (action.type) {
        ...

        case GET_DATA_SUCCESS:
            newState = action.payload;
            break;

        ...
```

I will call the API like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  getData: path => getData(path);
}

...

// Using dispatch
getData('/myDataPath');
```

**agent.js**

```
...

getData : {
    get = path => performGet('https://my.url/data' + path);
}
```

Now I know this works perfectly fine for performing a single GET to the endpoint and storing in Redux store under a single entry.

Is there a way in which I can store multiple responses in the Redux store entry?

Comment: Does `:varying-part` correspond to `agent: agent.getData.get`? Or how are you identifying each request?

Comment: @BrianThompson apologies. I've added an update to explain a little further.

Comment: Ok, so it's `agentData` that is unique for each request then?

Comment: Yeah it is. But I'm not sure how that is of any use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic property using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) in your state based on the `agentData` or other identifying piece of your action.

It would look something like this:

**Reducer**

```js
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  ...
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case GET_DATA_SUCCESS:
      newState = {
        ...state, // Keep all the other values (agentData entries)
        [action.agentData]: action.payload // Add/overwrite the current one
      };
      break;
      ...
```

Comment: How can one access the `agentData` here? I just tried consoling it out and it was `undefined`...

Comment: I'm basing this off of your code. Your action creator shows that the `action` object contains the `agentData` which is the `path` value. Is there another piece you're not including?

Comment: If you have a middleware that is setting the `payload`, but is not passing along other action properties, then this strategy will not work, but I have no way of knowing whether or not that's the case.

Comment: Ah I get you. I will have a dig through the code to see if there is any sneaky middleware scuppering things.

Comment: Ah it indeed looks like there's some middleware that needs adjusting in order to make your solution viable. Thanks for the help Brian :)

Comment: If adjusting middleware turns out not to be possible, then the only other option I can see is to use a dynamic type. But I would very strongly advice against that. It seems error-prone. At that point the flexibility may not be work the additional complexity anymore.

Comment: Yes, dynamic type was my initial thought given the lack of agentData being sent through, hence why I came here to ask for better help :P It looks like I've been able to get the agentData being passed through via the middleware now, relatively simply actually. So I should hopefully now be able to do what I am thinking :) Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I knew there would be something I hadn't thought about.